# "bash: Array and Bad substitution" when using do in .sh file

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I wuld like to create a script who run some program and check if they started or no, unfortunately I receive several error and I don't know why:

```
#!/bin/sh
# start file

c[0] = 'foo'
c[1] = 'mickey'
c[2] = 'mouse'

echo "Launching..."

for i in 0 1 2; do
        echo "Starting ${c[i]}"
        ${c[i]}
        ps cax | grep ${c[i]}
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "${c[i]} is running"
        else
        {
            echo "${c[i]} is not running"
            ${c[i]}
        } 
        fi
done

echo "launch completed."
```

when I try to run it, the shell don't recognize both the command name and I receive error also on the line

```
for i in 0 1 2; do
```

for "Bad substitution".

Can you please explain where I'm wrong with this script? Thanks in advance.

---- Update ----

Thanks to us for your REALLY PRECIOUS answers, I modified my script according to your advices:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start file


echo "Launching..."

for i in foo mickey mouse; do
        echo "Starting $i"
        $i
        ps cax | grep $i
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "$i is running"
        else
            echo "$i is not running"
            $i
        fi
done

echo "launch completed."
```

Thanks again!
Fabrizio

Comment: Do you not need to specify it as `$i`? Also what is with the braces? You're not declaring any functions, get rid of them.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` needs to be `#!/bin/bash` for bash-only features such as arrays. Even if it's a symlink to bash, it disables many non-POSIX features when invoked that way. (Also, as a matter of convention, executables shouldn't have `.sh` extensions -- that way the user doesn't need to know what language a thing is written in to be able to run it; also, `.sh` is misleading for scripts using bash-only features, which are not compatible with POSIX sh).

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you are using an array here at all. Just use `for i in foo mickey mouse`, and replace all the reference to elements of `c` with `$i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there's a few errors here, let's go through them from the start:

```
c[0] = 'foo'
c[1] = 'mickey'
c[2] = 'mouse'
```

`c` is undefined, and no spaces in assignments:

```
c=()
c[0]='foo'
c[1]='mickey'
c[2]='mouse'
```

For

```
    echo "Starting ${c[i]}"
    ${c[i]}
    ps cax | grep ${c[i]}
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "${c[i]} is running"
    else
    {
        echo "${c[i]} is not running"
        ${c[i]}
    } 
    fi
```

You need to refer to ${c[$i]} to access the index, $c[i] is referencing an index based on the character `i`, not the variable.

```
    echo "Starting ${c[$i]}"
    ${c[$i]}
    ps cax | grep ${c[$i]}
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "${c[$i]} is running"
    else
    {
        echo "${c[$i]} is not running"
        ${c[$i]}
    } 
    fi
```

Finally:

```
    else
    {
        echo "${c[$i]} is not running"
        ${c[$i]}
    } 
    fi
```

Bash doesn't use braces for if/else, get rid of them

```
    else
        echo "${c[$i]} is not running"
        ${c[$i]}
    fi
```

All done.

Comment: You don't need `${c[$i]}`. ${c[i]} works for me. Is there a reason why we shouldn't do that?

Comment: The braces are unnecessary, but harmless. `c=()` isn't necessary either, since the array-style assignment automatically makes `c` an array.

Comment: The bad substitution is due to the incorrect assignments resulting in `c` not being an array, not because `${c[i]}` is incorrect.

Comment: The first line also needs to be `!#/bin/bash` if the script is run as a command, but it will be ignored if you run it as `bash script.sh` (or whatever it is named).

Comment: It works fine in bash, thanks for explaination @scragar and to all :)

Anyway the array declaration is ok also without c() but assigning dinamically the value of the element :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
c[0] = 'foo'
c[1] = 'mickey'
c[2] = 'mouse'
```

to

```
c[0]='foo'
c[1]='mickey'
c[2]='mouse'
```

Comment: I've done but without success...

`fabrizio@fabrix:~/Documents$ sudo sh launch.sh 
launch.sh: 4: launch.sh: c[0]: not found
launch.sh: 5: launch.sh: c[1]: not found
launch.sh: 6: launch.sh: c[2]: not found
Launching...
launch.sh: 11: launch.sh: Bad substitution`

Comment: `sh` does not support arrays, even if it is a link to `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this code. Its not good to use 0 1 2 to iterate through the array because you might not know the size of the array. Its better to use ${c[@]} which would have all the elements of the array. This would be more dynamic and better

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # start file
 c=(foo mickey mouse)

  echo "Launching..."
  //below one to execute your foo or micckyor mouse command
  $i
  for i in ${c[@]}; do
    echo "Starting $i"
    ps cax | grep $i
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "$i is running"
    else
    {
        echo "$i is not running"
         //below one to execute your foo or micckyor mouse command
         $i
    }
    fi
 done

 echo "launch completed."
```